# How to have Google Chrome Canary on Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, google-chrome, compiling, browser, google

How can I have [Google Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/canary/) for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As stated in the site you linked, Canary builds are not available for Linux.

The only release channels available for Linux are: Stable, Beta and Dev.

[image]

The reason for that is explained [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/chromium-discuss/GNE4pEXLMkQ/cis32ewLosYJ):

> Thanks for your interesting in testing out the latest and greatest builds of Chrome.  There are logistical challenges that make creating/ deploying Linux bundles prohibitively expensive to do on a daily basis, which effectively makes a Linux Canary fairly unlikely for the foreseeable future.  I'd encourage the community to use the PPA builds, those are fundamentally the same as what we would build save for a couple of plugins (PDF, Flash, FFMpeg).
>
> Kind Regards,
>
> Anthony Laforge
> Technical Program Manager
> Mountain View, CA

Comment: where are the ppa builds?

Comment: The ppa builds are dead. [Use this instead](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/12/how-to-install-daily-builds-of-chrome-in-ubuntu)

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/510186/677955) shows how to install `google-chrome-stable` or `google-chrome-beta` or `google-chrome-unstable` by adding the [official 3rd party Chrome PPA](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome)

Answer (score 3):

Fallback place:

https://download-chromium.appspot.com/?platform=Linux_x64&type=snapshots

As the date of today 2019-02-07, this binary is Version 74.0.3697.0 (Developer Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Chromium Dev seria como Canary

**https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel**

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`puppeteer/browsers`](https://pptr.dev/) package:

```
npx @puppeteer/browsers@latest install chrome@canary
```

`npx` comes from https://npmjs.com/ (NodeJS).