# brotli on linux chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome

I read about the new compression algorithm by google called [Brotli](http://google-opensource.blogspot.it/2015/09/introducing-brotli-new-compression.html).

I would like try it on my laptop, but chrome browser doesn't support it yet. [Chrome Canary](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309813/how-to-have-ubuntu-chrome-canary) isn't available for linux.

So I ask If do you now a way to try Brotli on linux.

Answer (score 1):

You could build Chromium from source. There are instructions [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_build_instructions.md).

Brotli can be enabled in Chrome-like browsers via [chrome://flags#enable-brotli](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/net-dev/JufzX024oy0)

Brotli is also in Firefox from [version 44 onwards](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=366559). That's currently Firefox Beta so you could get that from [here](https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/channel/).

Comment: I installed Chromium with synaptic, now how can I enable brotli?

Comment: In (my) Chromium doesn't exist that flag.

Comment: With Firefox-beta v44, the brotli algorithm is already enable right?

Comment: I believe so, yes. There's no mention of a flag in the [release notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/44#HTTP)

Comment: reading these pages [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/44),  [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding) I believe too.